# Is there a software tool for auto testing API endpoints?

Tags: software-testing

I would like to test regularly API calls to measure service availability, eg: running through all the published API Calls of a service, logging in, registering, uploading a dummy file.

Is there a software toolkit that discovers API calls based on endpoints and auto generates test code, or does tests itself? Or creating a test for API endpoints would be a custom coding job?